# Incorrect output from using the Grep command

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to extract the unique occurrence with count using the script below. It is returning:

> " CCS Shadow Mode ERROR: OGS AND FE Request PayLoad are not matching"

I am unable to get the because of the number that occurs after that string. Can anyone help me how to remove the digits or hostname which occurs after the occurrence of the string?

my script:

```
grep -n 'CCS  ERROR.*' $dir/*.csv* | grep -oE 'CCS  ERROR.*' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr >>  /path/output.txt
```

file which has string

> martpay:signal2:auth:CCS ERROR: PayLoad are not
>   matching,51767703062,sXXXXpgsusapp620.
>
> auth:CCS ERROR: PayLoad are not
>   matching,51717613303049,sl55pgs20.xx.com
>
> auth:CCS ERROR:  PayLoad are not matching,517170803653,ssusapp055

Comment: Please use some formatting (you can use `code` formatting for source code as well as for your inputs), that will make your question so much easier to read.

Comment: There is an extra space for the string that you are grepping for i guess. Also, no need of '*' at the end of grepping strings and the '.' [dot] is not there in the string present in the mentioned file. TRY, 

`grep -n 'CCS ERROR' $dir/*.csv* | grep -oE 'CCS ERROR' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`